# How can I add my username to the top panel in Xenial Xerus?

Tags: unity, 16.04, panel

I would like to see my username in the top panel of Xenial Xerus. By *default* it is not present, as this screenshot demonstrates:

[image]

How can I place the logged in username there and then easily reverse this if I want? I am interested in both command line and gui solutions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard (and easiest) way to display your user name in the Unity panel is to launch **System Settings** and go to **User Accounts**.

You can see a checkbox at the bottom of the window that says

> Show my login name in the menu bar

Simply enable that checkbox and your display name appears in the top right corner of your screen.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The username of the currently logged in user can easily be placed in the top panel by using either:

1. A purely command line method
2. A gui method

**1. Command line method:**

Open a Terminal window with the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run the following command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session show-real-name-on-panel true
```

Below is a screenshot to demonstrate the successful result:

[image]

And this can be easily be subsequently reversed by running the following command in a Terminal window:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session show-real-name-on-panel false
```

Easy enough to do but some will always prefer a gui solution:

**2. Gui method:**

If you prefer to accomplish this from a gui install the `unity-tweak-tool` as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

The required setting can be found by opening the Tweak Tool and then following this path:

```
Unity >> Panel >> Indicators
```

The exact setting is illustrated in the screenshot below:

[image]

And of course the Unity Tweak Tool will allow many,many other small refinements...

Comment: Why are you suggesting that complicated methods? There's a far easier way to achieve this.

Comment: Anyway to get the `root` user's name up there? (No trolls please.)