# Show logged in user in Unity

Tags: unity

I an running Unity version 7.4.0+16.04.20160906 under Ubuntu 16.04.2

I would like to have the *user name* (or user ID number) displayed on the desktop (not in a window or any of a window's decoration) as soon as it starts up and perpetually thereafter.  After switching user, even for the first time (especially when that user first logs in) it should immediately show as soon as anything shows.  It does not need to show when the screen is black just before the display begins.  An ideal location would be somewhere along the title bar at the top.  *How can I do this?*

Comment: Do you mean [this feature](https://askubuntu.com/questions/795035/how-can-i-add-my-username-to-the-top-panel-in-xenial-xerus)?

Comment: @Redbob yes, except that my **user accounts** does not show that checkbox.

Comment: the 2nd unchecked answer worked.

Comment: Great! Vote up that answer and report this as your own answer..

Comment: it does not include the '\_' character.  some of my aws project users have '\_' in the name.  but i can live with this.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is copied with minor editing from an answer for the question [How can I add my username to the top panel in Xenial Xerus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/795035/how-can-i-add-my-username-to-the-top-panel-in-xenial-xerus) that @Redbob referred to in comments.

The username of the currently logged in user can easily be placed in the top panel by using either:

1. A purely command line method
2. A gui method

**1. Command line method:**

Open a Terminal window with the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run the following command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session show-real-name-on-panel true
```

Below is a screenshot to show the successful result:

[image: screenshot to show the successful result]

And this can be easily be subsequently reversed by running the following command in a Terminal window:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session show-real-name-on-panel false
```

Easy enough to do but some will always prefer a gui solution:

**2. Gui method:**

If you prefer to accomplish this from a gui install the `unity-tweak-tool` as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

The required setting can be found by opening the Tweak Tool and then following this path:

```
Unity >> Panel >> Indicators
```

The exact setting is illustrated in the screenshot below:

[image: screenshot to show the setting panel]

And of course the Unity Tweak Tool will allow many,many other small refinements...